# GameCenter hosted type upto 16 users

Tags: objective-c, game-engine, game-center, hosted

I am using Apple GameCenter which only allow to use maximum 4 users at time. I wanted to support it upto 16 users using hosted type game.
Apple says need to do some network configure on our own server.

Can anyone guide to setup? What to configure on our own server and how?